# VPN Tunneling through Multiple NAT environment

Tags: vpn, router, nat, isp, ddns

I currently building a DIY surveillance system based off of a QNAP NAS. The NAS will store the data, control the cameras, and act as a VPN Server for external access. 
I've managed to get all the the internal set-up functioning, but cannot access anything from outside my LAN (i.e. through ISP into my network). I have DDNS set-up, however, my ISP is NATing my DDNS IP through theirs so I cannot reach inside. ** Building location is remote, so ISP provides services via a wireless access-point to the internal router.

Is there anyway to get around this without switching ISPs?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Have the device behind the NATs VPN out to a rendezvous point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set up a VPS and change your VPN server into a client. Set up thebVPS as a VPN server. Then have your other sites connect to this VPN server. Make sure the VPN server knows how to route the traffic.